# Siebel WSDL and svcutil

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, .net-core

I want to make a C# client for a siebel product and it seems that they are not very friend.

I have this errors when I run

```
svcutil.exe siebel.wsdl
```

> Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool [Microsoft (R) Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation, Version 4.6.1055.0] Copyright (c) Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Error: There was an error verifying some XML Schemas generated during
>   export: The global element
>   'http://mydomain.tld/xml/ListData:ListOfData' has already been
>   declared.
>
> Error: There was an error verifying some XML Schemas generated during
>   export: The complexType
>   'http://mydomain.tld/xml/ListData:ListOfDataTopElmt' has already been
>   declared.
>
> Error: There was an error verifying some XML Schemas generated during
>   export: The complexType 'http://mydomain.tld/xml/ListData:ListOfData'
>   has already been declared.
>
> Error: There was an error verifying some XML Schemas generated during
>   export: The complexType 'http://mydomain.tld/xml/ListData:Data' has
>   already been declared.

Opening in SoapUI and checking WSDL content I have this:

[image]

And for each ListOfData I have this line:

```
<xsd:element name="ListOfData" type="xsdLocal3:ListOfData"/>

<xsd:element name="ListOfData" type="xsdLocal6:ListOfData"/>

<xsd:element name="ListOfData" type="xsdLocal5:ListOfData"/>

<xsd:element name="ListOfData" type="xsdLocal1:ListOfData"/>
```

How can I make it work nicely with svcutil?

I'm not a SOAP/WSDL expert at all, let me know if you need more information.

Thanks

Comment: It is not friendly, it has bugs in it. It probably references more than one .XSD and in those XSD declares the same type. It should either diferentiate the types declaring `ListOfCar`, `ListOfPerson` etc or declare the type in only a single XSD and reuse it.

Comment: You're probably right, the wsdl file I have gave me this feeling.